# Cuboid points coordinates in 3D

Tags: geometry, 3d, coordinate-systems

I have this gray cuboid, bounded by the white cube and I need to draw a line (the red line, which passes form the center of the edge, the center of the cuboid, to the other edge)
The info I have are the coordinates of the center, the orientation of the cuboid, and the position of the 2 corners of the cube (the 2 points that the green line passes between)

[image]

Is it possible to do so with the current info?

Comment: Can you be more precise about how the white cube bounds the gray cuboid? In other words, do you know that the vertices of the cuboid lie on the faces of the cube (for example) or just that the gray cuboid lies within the white cube? In the latter case, I doubt you have enough information. Also, from the diagram, it looks as though perhaps the cube and cuboid share the same center. Do you know that, or might it not be the case?

Comment: yes, the the vertices of the cuboid lie on the faces of the cube (except 2 of them ), the cub and the cuboid share the same center as well.

Comment: Aha. Presuming that "know the orientation" means you have the three vectors perpendicular to the faces of the cuboid, then you have three unknowns (the three dimensions of the cuboid) and you have three equations (the three conditions that vertices of the cuboid lie on faces of the cube), so chances are good you can solve for the three dimensions and determine the vertices of the cuboid and hence find the red line.

Comment: "Know the orientation", I meant by it that I know the rotation angle in degrees on the X,Y,Z axis. (: 
I'm sorry, I should've been more precis.

Comment: I believe my previous comment stands; with those angles, your only unknowns are the three dimensions of the cuboid, and you have three contact conditions, so you should be in luck.

Comment: I'm unable to detect the location of the interaction point between the cuboid vertex  and the cub face

I've been trying to solve this for the past 2 hours and no success.

Comment: Well, I am assuming that the cube is aligned with the coordinate axes or that you know its precise position. Hence you know the equation of the plane containing (say) its top face; if it's aligned with the axes, then that is just $z=c$ for some constant $c$. Let $l,w,h$ be the unknown dimensions of the gray cuboid. Then based on its orientation, you can write an expression in $l,w,h$ for the the "top" vertex of the cuboid. Since that touches the top face of the cube, you know it must satisfy the equation of that plane, in the simple case you just take the $z$-coordinate of the expression and..

Comment: .. set it equal to $c$. That gives you one equation in $l,w,h$. Do the same for the two other independent contact points (i.e., not the "bottom" vertex, which by symmetry will give you an equation equivalent to the first), and you will have three equations in $l,w,h$ which you solve, and then you know everything about the cuboid.

Comment: Ok, I get now.....
Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To sum up the discussion in the notes: The OP knows that the cuboid shares the same center as the cube and has six points of contact with the cube, and also knows the orientation of the cuboid. Also, the OP knows the equations of the planes of the faces of the cube. Therefore, the solution method is to let $l,w,h$ be the unknown dimensions of the gray cuboid. Then based on its orientation, you can write an expression in $l,w,h$ for the the "top" vertex of the cuboid. Since that touches the top face of the cube, you know it must satisfy the equation of that plane, which yields one equation in $l,w,h$. Do the same for the two other independent contact points (i.e., not the "bottom" vertex, which by symmetry will give you an equation equivalent to the first), and you will have three equations in $l,w,h$ which you solve, and then you know everything about the cuboid.